# Selenium Web driver Not able to find New window triggered after accepting the alert

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my problem what I am facing,

1. Login to the application
2. Goto a specfied module of my application
3. Entered all the details in the page.
4. Clicked on Save Button.
5. Got an alert and accepted it
6. On accepting the alert a new window poped up

I tried with the following code to find the active windows handles, but it is returning me value 1 all the time

```
Set<String> afterpopup = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println("Active windows" + afterpopup.size());
for(String currentwindow : afterpopup)
{
    System.out.println(currentwindow);
    if(!beforepopup.equalsIgnoreCase(currentwindow))
    {
        System.out.println("entered window loop");
        driver.switchTo().window(currentwindow);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

*What is the expected output? What do you see instead?*
I want to get the active windows (like main window + Popup window) in my case it should be 2 .

Selenium version:2.44
OS: Windows 7
Browser: Internet Explorer
Browser version: 8.0.7

Note : I am getting this error on popup window (window.opener.document is null or not an object ) . Please help me on this !!

Comment: Give a sleep time of 4-5 seconds before the code `Set<String> afterpopup = driver.getWindowHandles();` and check your output then. IE have a knack of responding slow. **And, if it still returns 1, then the opened window is a popup which is a part of the existing Parent window, and it's not a new window.**

Answer (score 0):

```
Using java8 you can use for insted 

public static String getNewWindow(WebDriver driver) {
    List<String> newWindow = driver.getWindowHandles().stream()
        .filter(n -> windows.contains(n) == false).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(newWindow.get(0));
    return newWindow.get(0);
  }
```